# A list of how every neutral mob returns to neutral after they have been provoked

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want a list of the *ways* or *duration* after which a neutral mob which has been already *provoked* turns back to *neutral* (Other than either of them **dying**).

---

I checked the main wiki and also [this page](https://minecraft-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Neutral) but only the above reason (either of them dying) is mentioned and I could make neutral mobs back to neutral by going out of its sight for a period of time (Which I want to know in the answer) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## All neutral-hostile mobs and how to calm them down

---

**Disclaimer:**

**All of these were tested on 1.16.5 and may be different on other versions**

*There are almost zero exact measurements and all are approximations, let's be honest when being hunted by an enderman will you really check the amount of seconds that have passed since you looked at it?*

***All mobs will not anger other mobs unless stated***

**Assume all mobs were tested on Normal, during the daytime, in the overworld, with a render distance of 16 and without leaving the world or changing dimesions unless stated.**

*(Technically it may be possible to manipulate mobs behavior by changing the render distance, or by leaving and entering the world but that would be a complicated process to test for.)*

---

**Bee** - After a 50 block distance they calm down. After stinging the player they calm down and die. Angering a bee without a stinger wont make it attack you again. Bees will anger other bees with or without stingers.

**Dolphin** - After hitting them they will no longer give you *Dolphin's Grace* *(If the dolphin gives its ability that dolphin is neutral).* Staying around 50 blocks away and coming back will make the dolphin neutral, and give you its ability.

**Enderman** - **Endermen have two cases**, on both cases going a distance of around 50 blocks away will calm them down *(I would advise finding an ocean because they move at high speeds).* The first case is **if you look an enderman in the eye**. The endermen you looked at will attack you for around 30 seconds and then stop attacking, **even if you look at it again.**. The second case is if you **hit an enderman**. An enderman that has been hit will not stop attacking until you go 50 blocks away.

**Panda** - Once a panda has been hit it will slowly follow the player. After going around 25 blocks away the panda will become neutral. If the **panda hits the player once**, *even if it has taken more than one damage from the player* it will become neutral.

**Llama** - After the llama is hit it will spit at you, once it spits it will become neutral, even if it doesn't hit. If the player hits the llama and the player is outside of the llama's range of around 25 blocks it will spit an indefinite amount of times, until the player re-enters the llama's range then it will become neutral *this could be a bug*.

**Polar Bear** - cases for polar bears. A "single" *(no child)* polar bear will follow the player once hit and attack until a 25 block distance is made. A baby polar bear will make all the nearby polar bears aggresive until a 25 block distance is made. Killing the baby polar bear will make the "parent" *(the polar bear that spawned with the child because baby polar bears dont spawn from spawn eggs)* aggresive until a 50 block distance is made.

**Piglin** - **TL;DR: Piglins that have witnessed you breaking any of their laws will be angry, unless you give them four gold objects or go at least 50 blocks away**

1. Not wearing any gold armor will make a piglin *(excluding children, except brutes they will always attack)* mad at you until you wear some.
2. Punching a piglin *(including children and brutes)* will make it and all other nearby piglins angry until a 25-ish block distance is made from the closest aggresive piglins.
3. Killing a Piglin (including brutes and children) will make all nearby *(wider range than punching one)* piglins aggresive, until a 50 block distance is made from the closest aggresive piglin.
4. Breaking a chest, gilded blackstone, gold ore, nether gold ore, or a gold block will make them angry until a 50 block distance is made from the closest angry piglin.
5. **Most important:** ***Angry piglins will not anger other piglins who were not in range when you commited a "piglin crime" will not be aggresive. Piglin Brutes *(that you have not comitted a crime against)* will not make other piglins aggressive. Zombified piglins will not make regular piglins aggresive. Piglins that have been zombified by being in the overworld will not make other piglins aggresive, but will instead make zombiefied piglins aggressive***

**Zombiefied Piglins** - Once attacked they will make all other zombified piglins in the area aggresive until a 128 block distance is put between you and the closest aggresive zombiefied piglin. Piglins that have been turned into zombiefied piglins will also become hostile if there are aggressive zombiefied piglins nearby until a 128 block distance is made. *Changing yourself or the zombiefied piglin from the overworld to the nether will not remove the "aggresive-ness"*

**Spider/Cave Spider** - During the day/high light levels: Spider's are not aggresive, once attacked they will become aggresive until a 50 block distance is made. During the night/caves/low light levels: spiders are aggresive and will attack until killed, even if the sun rises or the light level increases the spider will still be aggresive unless a 50 block distance is made. **Cave Spiders act the same, although it's highly unlikely you will find one exposed to daylight.**

**Wandering Trader Llamas** - Unlike the normal llamas wandering trader llamas, are trained to run away. After being hit the llama will run in circles for a bit and then spit at you. The spit does not have to hit, however if you are not in the llamas range it will wait until you are visible and then spit at you. If the Wandering Trader that owns the llamas is killed, the llamas will initiate "turret mode" and will spit at you until a 50 block distance is made, the same will happen if it's llama partner is killed ***(this statement comes from memory since I couldn't make a wandering trader with llamas spawn)***.

**Wolf** - Attacking a wolf will make it and any wolf nearby angry until the player is maybe more than 200 blocks away. There is no other way to calm down a wolf without doing things outside of the game *(like leaving and re-entering the world)*

**Iron Golems** - Iron Golems spawned from villages are neutral until provoked. Hitting an iron golem will provoke it. Killing a villager, or sometimes hurting the villager to very low health will provoke it. On Villager murder the iron golem will never stop running after you, it will swim through water and even leave the village it is trying to protect. Iron Golems do not make other Iron Golems aggresive, neither will killing the Iron Golem in front of an Iron Golem. Similar to Piglins the Iron Golem has to "witness" *(be near the murdered villager)* in order to be aggresive. **The only way to calm down an Iron Golem is to kill it.**

Comment: If there are any questions or if I missed something or got something wrong please let me know so I can fix the issues.

Comment: This is some really useful information, though what would the situation be like with village-spawned iron golems? Also there's cave spiders, but I would guess that it's the same as regular spiders.

Comment: @BlueTangsRock  I completely forgot about Iron Golems, I also assumed that Cave Spiders are always aggresive. When In fact they act like regular spiders. I've added both of those now.

Comment: Thanks, this was excellent.